# Someone else is using the Excel file, but not really

Tags: excel, powerquery, export-to-excel

I'm facing an issue in an Excel file (used by all members of my department) hosted in an internal server.

Sometimes, we cannot even save this file while working on it. When we try to save it, it shows us a message saying that someone is working on it (but it doesn't apparently, because we were able to open in editor mode). The message displayed is "Someone else is working in [folder/file path] right now. Please try again later".

I've done some research and I'm suspecting that is due to a Power Query connection between this file and another spreadsheet.

So, my question is: how can I solve this problem without losing my Power Query connection? Is there any way to ask Power Query to only establish a connection in read mode or something like that?

Tks!

Re write my query or create a macro to copy this file to another folder and establish my Power Query connection with this copy.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74546107/how-to-set-read-only-for-power-query-connection